# Getting data from a mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a fairly simple issue with MySQL. I just don't know the syntax well.

CODE:

```
$Rego_select = mysql_query(
  "SELECT VechicleRegistration FROM trucks WHERE TruckID = '$truckID'" ) 
  or die("Problem reading table: " . mysql_error());`
```

If i try to echo $Rego_select directly it outputs Resource Locater #. I am wondering what function I can use to get the data from that column.

I tried to use mysql_result(); but it requires a position number which makes life difficult because I am executing this query dynamically in a while statement and I would have to re write the whole loop structure if this is the only way to do it.

Cheers guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `mysql_result()`. The position it requires is just the position in the result. When executing a query like that, there's only one result. `mysql_result($Rego_select,0)` should yield the result.

Comment: Thanks mate. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_result($query)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

But don't quote me on that, I've been using ADODB for so long now I can't remember the mysql_etc syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
  $Rego_select = mysql_query(
      "SELECT VechicleRegistration FROM trucks WHERE TruckID = '$truckID'" ) ;

       if($Rego_select)
          {
              while($row=mysql_fetch_object($Rego_select))
                {
                if( $row->VechicleRegistration )
             echo   $valid= $row->VechicleRegistration ;
                }   
                }    

?>
```